# Where can I find a guide on how to create Matlab code with a low storage consumption for use on microcontrollers?

Tags: matlab, optimization, storage, microcontroller

As the Autosar portion of our flash image uses most of our storage resources on the micro we need also to optimise our Matlab code. Is there a checklist or a guide to give an indication on how to design code efficiently for use on a microcontroller?
Thank you for any hint.
Volker

Answer (score 0):

You might check out the Mathworks article: [Best Practices for a MATLAB to C Workflow Using Real-Time Workshop](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/best-practices-for-a-matlab-to-c-workflow-using-real-time-workshop.html).